# Ninject ASP.NET Identity The type '.....' cannot be used as type parameter 'TImplementation' in the generic type or method

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-identity-2, ninject.web.mvc

I'm getting a few compiler errors about my bindings with `Ninject`. This is the code:

```
kernel.Bind<IUserStore<ApplicationUserStore>>().To<UserStore<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>>().InRequestScope();
kernel.Bind<IRoleStore<ApplicationRoleStore>>().To<RoleStore<ApplicationRole, int, ApplicationUserRole>>().InRequestScope();
```

And these are the compiler errors:

> Error 5   The type 'MyNamespace.Data.ApplicatonRoleStore' cannot be used as type parameter 'TRole' in the generic type or method 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IRoleStore'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'MyNamespace.Data.ApplicatonRoleStore' to 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IRole'.
>
> Error 6   The type 'MyNamespace.Data.ApplicatonRoleStore' cannot be used as type parameter 'TRole' in the generic type or method 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IRoleStore'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'MyNamespace.Data.ApplicatonRoleStore' to 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IRole'.
>
> Error 2   The type 'MyNamespace.Data.ApplicatonUserStore' cannot be used as type parameter 'TUser' in the generic type or method 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUserStore'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'MyNamespace.Data.ApplicatonUserStore' to 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUser'.
>
> Error 3   The type 'MyNamespace.Data.ApplicatonUserStore' cannot be used as type parameter 'TUser' in the generic type or method 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUserStore'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'MyNamespace.Data.ApplicatonUserStore' to 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUser'.
>
> Error 4   The type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.RoleStore' cannot be used as type parameter 'TImplementation' in the generic type or method 'Ninject.Syntax.IBindingToSyntax.To()'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.RoleStore' to 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IRoleStore'.
>
> Error 1   The type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore' cannot be used as type parameter 'TImplementation' in the generic type or method 'Ninject.Syntax.IBindingToSyntax.To()'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore' to 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUserStore'.

By default the `asp.net-identity` system uses the guid for primary key. I altered that to use ints instead. I can see some errors about `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IRole<string>`.

EDIT:
These are the classes:

```
public class ApplicationRoleStore : RoleStore<ApplicationRole, int, ApplicationUserRole>
{
    public ApplicationRoleStore(ApplicationDbContext context)
        : base(context)
    { }
}

public class ApplicationUserStore :
    UserStore<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
{
    public ApplicationUserStore(ApplicationDbContext context)
        : base(context)
    { }
}
```

Comment: All those seems to point to a missing interface implementation as the compiler errors tell, as it tries to convert from your concrete class to that interface.

Comment: It looks like you are performing an invalid registration. Can you show us the Interface and the Class definition for the target object?

Comment: I added the classes about which the compiler is complaining. @alejandro, I'm not sure which interface I'm missing, but that's all the user and rolestore have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. In case someone else stumbles into this, this is how:

```
kernel.Bind<IAuthenticationManager>().ToMethod(c => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication); //.InRequestScope();

kernel.Bind<IRoleStore<ApplicationRole, int>>().To<RoleStore<ApplicationRole, int, ApplicationUserRole>>()
            .WithConstructorArgument("context", context => kernel.Get<ApplicationDbContext>());

kernel.Bind<IUserStore<ApplicationUser, int>>()
            .To<UserStore<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>>()
            .WithConstructorArgument("context", context => kernel.Get<ApplicationDbContext>());
```

Not sure if `IAuthenticationManager` should be `InRequestScope`, but for now I left that part out.

And for the managers you'd to it like this:

```
kernel.Bind<UserManager<ApplicationUser, int>>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
kernel.Bind<RoleManager<ApplicationRole, int>>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
```